# Running a non-Activity class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I have more of a understanding problem. 
I added a new class in my Android porject. The class is not an Activity class, it uses objects of also non-activity classes to get some information. 
However, I can not test, if it does its job. I can not debug it, none of the Log- messages that I built in the code show up in logcat.
How can I test a class in a project otherwise?

I have pretty limited knowledge in java+Android+Eclipse, so I don't know, which one is the issue here.

Please help.

Comment: check that u call it from Android Activity ??

Comment: assuming you use the non-Activity class in an Activity, then you can test/log the output returned to the activity.

Comment: read the anddev book : http://andbook.anddev.org/. The gap is too deep if you don't understand the platform a minimum.

Comment: @Snicolas, I'm on it right now. I will try all the answers posted here. thanks to all of you

Comment: I am using the non-activity class in an Activity like Mustafa and iturki suggested and I can test it now.Thanks. So, if you post your comment as an answer, I could check it.

Answer (score 0):

Create test `Activity`, add there some UI elements which do some logic with your `non-Activity class`, and test it

Answer (score 0):

Add a class with

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

and run it.

E.g.

```
public class Runner {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //do smth here
}
```

}

Comment: This merely re-creates the problem it attempts to solve.  The question of how the second piece of code would be executed on an Android device replaces the question of how the poster's class would be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply develop a basic Activity with buttons that trigger the functions of your class